# How to handle an unhandled exception that is caused by a network error when loading a code-split file in vue 3/vite?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-router, vite

I have a project in Vue 3 that uses Vite to do code splitting. It is working great when the user's network is good. However, the app contains the handler:

```
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(event) {
```

so that I can find as many javascript errors as possible.

If the user's internet is flaky, so that the first route works but when they change routes it would load some more javascript but that javascript fails to load, the above handler is called with `event.reason = "TypeError: Load failed"`.

I am able to figure out in individual cases that this is harmless but that same error could be something I should be concerned with so I don't want to suppress it. I do want this problem to not clutter the log file, though.

Is there a way I can catch that error so it isn't unhandled? I have no idea what I would put a `try ... catch` around, though.

(Also, I'm assuming that the javascript files are loaded somewhere in the vue-router code, but I'm not sure what is loading them, so it might not be router-related.)